# How to find trace of adj$A$ from the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Tags: matrices

Let the characteristic polynomial for $A$ be $t^n+c_1 t^{n-1}+c_2t^{n-2}+\cdots+c_{n-1}t+c_n$. From it, is it possible to find the trace of adj$(A)$ ?

Comment: Upps!!! very sorry

Comment: Yap, now editing is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$,

$$
{\sf trace}(adj(A))={\sf trace}(\det(A)A^{-1})=
\lambda_1\lambda_2\ldots \lambda_n (\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\lambda_n})=
(-1)^{n-1}c_{n-1}
$$

This stays true for nondiagonalizable $A$’s because the diagonalizable matrices form a dense subset of $M_n({\mathbb R})$.

Comment: +1. However, if I understand correctly, I believe you mean $c_{n-1}$ instead of $c_2$.

Comment: @user2097 : corrected, thanks.

Comment: @user2097 but anyway, the solution is really nice and beautiful. thank you so much

Comment: Isn't this also true trigonalizable?

Comment: @Ale It is true for all matrices.